# Calculate sum of lines and compare to other table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I have Two tables

**TABLE A:**

```
  ID|Name |TotalAmount  
1234|Test1|120.00  
1235|Test2|1456.68
```

**TABLE B:**

```
  ID|Name  |LineAmount  
1234|Test1A|80.00  
1234|Test1B|40.00  
1235|Test2A|1000.08  
1235|Test2B|0.60  
1235|Test2C|56.00  
1235|Test2D|400.00
```

I want to calculate sum of **TABLE B** Lines with the same ID and Compare Total to **TABLE A**, how should I approach this problem?

### EDIT

What I want:

1. Get data from both Tables
2. Check if **SUM([TABLE B].LineAmount)** on ID is equal to **[TABLE A].TotalAmount**
3. If it's not add another **TABLE B** Line with the difference
4. Output everything in **Flat Files**

What I don't know is how can I compare if the summed amounts are equal to total amount. And if case it's not do something extra.

Comment: What do you mean by compare? What do you want to be returned?

Comment: You have an SSIS tag but I see no SSIS in the question. Can you edit your question to address this + Filipe's comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "compare".  The following produces the differences:

```
select coalesce(a.id, b.id) as id, a.TotalAmount, bsum.TotalLineAmount,
       (a.TotalAmount - bsum.TotalLineAmount) as difference
from TableA a full outer join
     (select b.id, sum(LineAmount) as TotalLineAmount
      from TableB b
      group by b.id
     ) bsum
     on a.id = bsum.id;
```

This uses a `full outer join` in case some ids are in one table but not the other.